# script to change old file to timestamp

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am working on a script using #!/bin/csh -f
this script is designed to do a bunch of things but one of the things is its suppose to move file_1 to file_old and the problem is whenever you have already ran the script and there is already has a file_old it says sorry cant help ya and exits out.  Is there something I can add to the script to change the old file to file_time stamp?

Comment: With GNU mv you can do `mv --backup=numbered file_1 file_old`, and it will be renamed `file_old.~6~` or whatever's the smallest available number if file_old already exists. Maybe that would be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
timestamp=\`date +%s\`
```

you can use append the `$timestamp` variable to your filename how you want it, that will give you a unique name.

Answer (score 0):

```
mv -f file_new file_old
```

Use option `-f`.

Comment: If you support your answer with a little brief that will help !!